# JQuery "includes" confusion

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

I want to use this verical slider implementation: http://www.elmundio.net/projects/verticalSlider/ which uses this files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" />
        <link href="http://www.elmundio.net/projects/verticalSlider/verticalSlider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.elmundio.net/projects/verticalSlider/verticalSlider.js"></script>
```

but I also need to use this files for my other stuff:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
        <script  src="jquery-1.9.1.js"> </script>
        <script  src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

How can I achieve compatibility between these files.

Comment: I'd first at least try and see if your vertical slider will work with jquery 1.9.1. If it does, then no problem! You could also ask whether your own code really needs version 1.9.1 as well. If you absolutely need both versions, then you'll need `noConflict` to keep them separate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery's [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to achieve the compatibility you want.